# Monitor rotation is disabled in Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: monitor, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate, preferences

I opened `Monitor Preferences` dialog in Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 on Raspberry Pi 3 and clicking on `Rotation` button shows only `Normal` option. Is there a way to set portrait (90 degrees rotation) mode?

**EDIT**

Adding `display_rotate=3` line to `/boot/config.txt` file, rotates the display, but I would prefer GUI configuration to work as well.

Comment: Does `display_rotate=3` really rotate the terminal for you? It doens't work for me on Ubuntu server.

Comment: @HolaSoyEduFelizNavidad It worked for me on Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1